# FluorineFx solution to read response

Tags: c#, .net, amf, fluorinefx

Here is class to read response from netConnection.Call:

```
    public class getCompleteParkOfUser : IPendingServiceCallback
    {
        public void ResultReceived(IPendingServiceCall call)
        {
            object result = call.Result;
            MessageBox.Show("Server response: " + result);
            ArrayCollection items = result as ArrayCollection;
            foreach (object item in items)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("");
            }

        }
    }
```

result is good: http://scr.hu/0tgp/6yxdi
but result won't be saved as ArrayCollection:
http://scr.hu/0tgp/ovghm
In effect i can't read response.

Response/Request is AMF

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
object item = call.Result;
IEnumerable enumerable = (IEnumerable)item;
foreach (object element in enumerable)
{
    // do something with element
}
```